# PHP: $_POST is not working, and GET method is shown on the browser instead

Tags: php, android, post, android-volley

I wrote a code to receive POST variables from android clients. When the POST request is made in the Android side, the PHP will receive each variable and take next processes.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['tag']) && !empty($_POST['tag'])) {

    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // get the variables.
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    // response Array
    $response = array();

    require_once 'mysql/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'login') {

        // check for user
        $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
        if ($user != false) {
            // user found
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else if ($tag == 'register') {

        // check if user is already exists

        if ($db->userExists($email)) {

            // user already exists - error response
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already exists";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {

            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $password);

            if ($user) {
                // user successfully saved to MySQL database.
                $response["error"] = FALSE;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];

                echo json_encode($response);

            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // user failed to store
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "Unknow 'tag' value. It should be either 'login' or 'register'";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Operation failed due to the missing tag!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}

var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $_POST);
?>
```

But when I opened this raw PHP file on the web to see how it looks, I found something very weird. It says as follows.

```
{"error":true,"error_msg":"Operation failed due to the missing tag!"}string(3) "GET" array(0) { }
```

that "GET" is the one I think very weird, because on either PHP or the Android side I never used the GET methods and it is present on the browser. How does this happen and what do I have to do to change that into POST?

edited:

Here's the Android part that requests a POST method. Volley library is used here.

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("tag", "register");
params.put("name", name);
params.put("email", email);
params.put("password", password);

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST, ServerURL.URL_REGISTER, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.d(TAG_REGISTER, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
        pDialog.dismiss();

        try {
            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response.toString());
            boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
            if (!error) {
                // User successfully stored in MySQL
                // Now store the user in sqlite
                String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                String name = user.getString("name");
                String email = user.getString("email");
                String created_at = user
                        .getString("created_at");

                // Inserting row in users table
                db.addUserIntoSQLite(name, email, uid, created_at);

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // Launch main activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().finish();

            } else {

                // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                // message
                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "JSONException: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(TAG_REGISTER, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}) {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        return headers;
    }
};

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

}

Comment: Can you show the code which makes this request? Be it android or html?

Comment: `GET` is the request method. If you open this file normally in a browser, it is opened using the `GET` method, and the reason you see this in the output is `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], $_POST);`. (Note that it's not just `"GET"` by itself, the whole `string(3) "GET"` belongs together). Also, if you `var_dump($_GET)`, are you getting anything, or is it empty as well as `$_POST`?

Comment: Looks like the parameters aren't being passed at all to the script. show the source code for the form that's submitting the data.

Comment: @DarylGill I uploaded the Android part. Thx

Comment: @ROAL Whenever I send the request to the server with tag, I don't receive anything, so it always returns that the tag is missing.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't just open the file in the browser and expect `POST` request to happen. You can only achieve `GET` request using that method.

I'm not sure why you're method is not working but given that your `IF` statement is failing you can easily test what kind of data is being passed through. Try doing the following before your first `IF` condition:

`var_dump($_POST);
echo '=====';
var_dump($_GET);`

This way you'll be able to tell what kind of data is being passed through when you make your `POST` request. From there you can debug and adjust your `IF` condition as that seems to be the main problem.